# Iterating over a specific row of a react ag-grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I got an `ag-grid` with a button rendered in a dedicated column (meaning each row has a button on the side under that column). I've done it like this:

```
const columnDefinition = [
                          {headerName: '', cellRenderer: 'editButton'},
                          {headerName: "Key", field: "Key"},
                          {headerName: "Value", field: "Value"}];

const overlayParams = {
  frameworkComponents: {
                        editButton: EditMagnifierButton, //EditMagnifierButton is a react functional component which renders a button
                       }
return (
 <Ag-Grid-React
     rowData={myRowData}
     columnDefs={columnDefinition} 
     {...overlayParams} />
);
```

I want to know how to iterate over the row where the user clicked the button and get all the values in each column of the row so i can pass them as props to another component.

The `EditMagnifierButton`:

```
const EditMagnifier = (props) =>
{
    return (
        <IconButton iconSvg={search} />
    )
}
```

Comment: WIthin your EditMagnifierButton component, you must be getting props.data which will point to your complete row data.

Comment: @S_learner the question is how to get to get the data in order to set it in props.data

Comment: ag-Grid takes care of that for you, ag-Grid injects some predefined props to your cellRenderer which already has data property into it.
Please refer here,
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#cell-renderer-component

Comment: @S_learner could you make an answer with a React JS code that shows how to read not just the row's index but to use it in order to iterate over all the data in the row? I'll accept it if it works

Comment: would you mind sharing your code for EditMagnifierButton component? I will make the changes in that itself.

Comment: @S_learner Added. As of now it does nothing besides rendering the button as I still don't know how to iterate over the row so I didn't implement the onClick event yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in ag-Grid docs, ag-Grid passes some default props to each cell-renderer and these props are in the format of **ICellRendererParams**,

```js
interface ICellRendererParams {
    value: any, // value to be rendered
    valueFormatted: any, // value to be rendered formatted
    getValue: () => any, // convenience function to get most recent up to date value
    setValue: (value: any) => void, // convenience to set the value
    formatValue: (value: any) => any, // convenience to format a value using the column's formatter
    data: any, // the row's data
    node: RowNode, // row node
    colDef: ColDef, // the cell's column definition
    column: Column, // the cell's column
    rowIndex: number, // the current index of the row (this changes after filter and sort)
    api: GridApi, // the grid API
    eGridCell: HTMLElement, // the grid's cell, a DOM div element
    eParentOfValue: HTMLElement, // the parent DOM item for the cell renderer, same as eGridCell unless using checkbox selection
    columnApi: ColumnApi, // grid column API
    context: any, // the grid's context
    refreshCell: () => void // convenience function to refresh the cell
}
```

Detail can be found under,
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#cell-renderer-component

So, there is one property called **data** which points to the rowData pointing to the index where the cell-renderer is present (in this case, the clicked one).

So your cell-renderer can use this prop directly as **props.data**,

```js
/* Here the props will point to ICellRendererParams */
const EditMagnifier = (props) =>
{

    const printRowData = (event) => {
      /* This will give you the complete row data for the clicked row*/
      console.log(props.data);
    }
    
    return (
        <IconButton iconSvg={search} onClick={printRowData}/>
    )
}
```

Comment: will the EditMagnifier  component be given the props automatically even though I don't pass them in my code when i render it?

Comment: yes exactly, thats what is managed by ag-Grid.

Comment: btw what if i want to add props of my own? how do i do that?

Comment: You can use cellRendererParams to pass your own props,
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#complementing-cell-renderer-params